# Final return statement, ignore

Tags: java, if-statement, return, conditional-statements

Im working on a token iterator (valid tokens, "true, false, "true", "&", "!", "(", "false", "^", "true", ")".

The code is working, my question is about return values.  I often run into this problem, I have return statements, but the final return statement throws off my result by duplicating the last return statement.

I think I know for sure the error lays within my placement of { and } and while i've learned they aren't necessary, since there's so many nested if's i feel they are necessary.

This seems to be a common problem to me and others ive worked with, does anyone have an idea of how to prevent this problem from happening? Thanks!

My code outputs:

line: [ ! BAD (true ^ false) % truelybad]
next token: [!]

next token: [(]

next token: [true]

next token: [^]

next token: [false]

next token: [)]

next token: [)]

and should output

next token: [!]

next token: [(]

next token: [true]

next token: [^]

next token: [false]

next token: [)]

```
public class TokenIter implements Iterator<String> {
ArrayList<String> token = new ArrayList<String>();
static int count = 0;
// input line to be tokenized
private String line;

// the next Token, null if no next Token
private String nextToken;

// implement
public TokenIter(String line) {
    this.line = line;

}

@Override
// implement
public boolean hasNext() {
    // System.out.println(count);
    return count < line.length();
}

@Override
// implement
public String next() {
    while (hasNext()) {

        char c = line.charAt(count);
        if (c == '!' || c == '!' || c == '^' || c == '(' || c == ')') {
            token.add(Character.toString(c));
            count++;
            nextToken = Character.toString(c);
            return nextToken;
                } else if (c == 't' || c == 'T') {
                    count++;
                    c = line.charAt(count);
                        if (c == 'r') {
                            count++;
                            c = line.charAt(count);
                            }
                                if (c == 'u') {
                                    count++;
                                    c = line.charAt(count);
                                }
                                    if (c == 'e') {
                                        count++;
                                        c = line.charAt(count);

                                    }if (c == ' ' || c == '!' || c == '!' || c == '^' || c == '(' || c == ')'){
                                        token.add("true");

                                        nextToken = "true";
                 //count++;
                                        return nextToken;
                                    }

        } else if (c == 'f' || c == 'F') {
            count++;
            c = line.charAt(count);
            if (c == 'a') {
                count++;
                c = line.charAt(count);
            }
            if (c == 'l') {
                count++;
                c = line.charAt(count);
            }
            if (c == 's') {
                count++;
                c = line.charAt(count);
            }
            if (c == 'e') {
                count++;
                c = line.charAt(count);

            }
            if (c == ' ' || c == '!' || c == '!' || c == '^' || c == '(' || c == ')'){
                token.add("false");

                nextToken = "false";
                // count++;
                return nextToken;
            }

        } else if (c == ' ') {
            count++;
        } else {
            count++;
        }

    }


    return nextToken;
}

@Override
// provided, do not change
public void remove() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}

// provided
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String line;
    // you can play with other inputs on the command line
    if (args.length > 0)
        line = args[0];
    // or do the standard test
    else
        line = " ! BAD (true ^ false) % truelybad";
    System.out.println("line: [" + line + "]");
    TokenIter tokIt = new TokenIter(line);
    while (tokIt.hasNext())
        System.out.println("next token: [" + tokIt.next() + "]");
}
```

}

Comment: *"final return statement ... duplicating the last return statement"* That's pretty confusing given that only **one** return statement is executed per method invocation.

Comment: @Andreas He means that his return statement sometimes just returns the last thing it returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem with your code comes only when last digit is not a token.
Reason - You are checking hasNext() which is true it goes inside your code.You are not setting nextToken for this case so it uses your lask token and display it. 
I updated your code to always return a value and check if value return is from token list then display otherwise ignore it.

```
   public class test implements Iterator<String> {
            static List<String> tokenList = Arrays.asList( "true", "&", "!", "(", "false", "^", "true", ")");
            ArrayList<String> token = new ArrayList<String>();
            static int count = 0;
            // input line to be tokenized
            private String line;

            // the next Token, null if no next Token
            private String nextToken;

            // implement
            public test(String line) {
                this.line = line;

            }

            @Override
            // implement
            public boolean hasNext() {
                // System.out.println(count);
                return count < line.length();
            }

            @Override
            // implement
            public String next() {
                while (hasNext()) {

                    char c = line.charAt(count);
                    if (c == '!' || c == '!' || c == '^' || c == '(' || c == ')') {
                        token.add(Character.toString(c));
                        count++;
                        nextToken = Character.toString(c);
                        return nextToken;
                    } else if (c == 't' || c == 'T') {
                        count++;
                        c = line.charAt(count);
                        if (c == 'r') {
                            count++;
                            c = line.charAt(count);
                        }
                        if (c == 'u') {
                            count++;
                            c = line.charAt(count);
                        }
                        if (c == 'e') {
                            count++;
                            c = line.charAt(count);

                        }if (c == ' ' || c == '!' || c == '!' || c == '^' || c == '(' || c == ')'){
                            token.add("true");

                            nextToken = "true";
                            //count++;
                            return nextToken;
                        }

                    } else if (c == 'f' || c == 'F') {
                        count++;
                        c = line.charAt(count);
                        if (c == 'a') {
                            count++;
                            c = line.charAt(count);
                        }
                        if (c == 'l') {
                            count++;
                            c = line.charAt(count);
                        }
                        if (c == 's') {
                            count++;
                            c = line.charAt(count);
                        }
                        if (c == 'e') {
                            count++;
                            c = line.charAt(count);

                        }
                        if (c == ' ' || c == '!' || c == '!' || c == '^' || c == '(' || c == ')'){
                            token.add("false");

                            nextToken = "false";
                            // count++;
                            return nextToken;
                        }

                    } else if (c == ' ') {
                        count++;
                        nextToken = null;
                    } else {
                        count++;
                        nextToken = null;
                    }

                }


                return nextToken;
            }

            @Override
            // provided, do not change
            public void remove() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
            }

            // provided
            public static void main(String[] args) {
                String line;
                // you can play with other inputs on the command line
                if (args.length > 0)
                    line = args[0];
                // or do the standard test
                else
                    line = " ! BAD (true ^ false) % truelybad ";
                System.out.println("line: [" + line + "]");
                test tokIt = new test(line);
                while (tokIt.hasNext()) {
                    String s = tokIt.next();
                    if (s != null && tokenList.contains(s))
                    System.out.println("next token: [" + s + "]");
                }
            }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The underlying problem here is that your `hasNext()` method returns true not if there is another token in the String, but if it hasn't finished parsing the String yet.

So what happens is if you put in the String `" ! ! true lotsofcrap "`, then calling `next()` will return `"!"`, then `"!"`, then `"true"`, then after that has been returned, there are no more tokens in the String, yet `hasNext()` still returns true.

What you might consider doing is having `hasNext()` parse through the string, but instead of returning the next String, return true only if it finds another token ahead of the current position. Keep in mind that in `hasNext()`, you do not want to directly increment `count`. Instead, make a local variable `int something = count;` at the beginning of `hasNext()` and use that.  If you fix that, then the rest of your code **SHOULD** work just fine.